# what does np.eye(n)[nparray] mean?

Tags: numpy

I am going thru some code

```
y_enc = np.eye(21)[label]
```

where label is ndarray of shape (224, 224)
y_enc is ndarray of shape (224, 224, 21)

Even with the shapes printed, I am having trouble understanding this statement. np.eye is supposed to generate a diagonal matrix of dimension 21 x 21. what does it mean to have [label] following it?

Comment: please provide reference to that other question.

Comment: This is indexing a NumPy array using another array as described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays . The first array is the Identity matrix of dimension 21 x 21. The second array selects the one-hot row corresponding to each label.

Answer (score 11):

From [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html). **numpy.eye**

> Return a 2-D array with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

Example:

```
>>np.eye(3)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.eye(3)[1]
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

`[label]` is array element indexing. So with only one element in it, it returns given number of rows element as array.

```
>>> np.eye(3)[1]
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
>>> np.eye(3)[2]
array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])
```

as it is `2d` array you can also access the specific element by giving 2 index number on `[row_index, column_index]`

```
>>> np.eye(3)[2,1]
0.0
>>> np.eye(3)[2,2]
1.0
>>> np.eye(3)[1,1]
1.0
```

Comment: don't think you quite nailed it. label is itself an adarray. not just a list of indices. Also, the indices of label way exceeds 21. As I said, y_enc ends up with a shape of (224, 224, 21)

Comment: ok. than how you explain about this error. `>>> a=np.eye(21)[224,224,21]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
`

Comment: You didn't answer the question, bro. Try this and answer how does this command generates the result. `a = np.array([[2,0],[1,2]]);np.eye(3)[a]`.